# Is it possible to secure Kibana UI using Ranger

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, hortonworks-sandbox, apache-ranger

I create a Kibana dashboard using HDFS data.(Note: I connect Elasticsearch with Hotonworks using Elasticsearch-Hadoop).I want to secure Kibana Dashboard.Is it possible to do that Security function with Ranger.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. You can check documentation which shows [what projects does Apache Ranger support](https://ranger.apache.org/faq.html#What_components_does_Apache_Ranger_support_today).

I your case you can use:

- [X-Pack](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack) - great security plugin for Elasticsearch and Kibana, but it is paid.
- [Search Guard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard) - free Elasticsearch and Kibana security plugin. I think it is very good tool.

But if you don't want to deploy a real security plugin (which contains SSL etc.) or something like that and you only need dashboard security you can use Kibana Own Home plugin. It is multitenancy plugin for Kibana which creates separate `.kibana` index for every user. It works with Apache httpd or nginx. Read more [here](https://github.com/wtakase/kibana-own-home).